# is there any solution to add css file to php page, while i am using a url segment function

Tags: php

i am trying to convert a static website to PHP base, so I have a currently developed css and javascript tree including bootstrap, what is the easiest way to add all of this files to my website,
I've tried include method, but not working. and  in  also not working

Comment: Show us the code what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add css, js file into php page, it's very simple, here is my solution for that: about normal php page's structure, it's gonna look like this. Your html is gonna be placed at bottom, and php is gonna be setup on the top.
So at this point, you can list all your current css, js into a object variable with structure may look like this:

```
$files_arr = [
    "css" => ["path_css_1", "path_css_2", ...],
    "js" => ["path_js_1", "path_js_2", ...]
];
```

And after that, inside of you `head` tag, run a loop for an initialized array above, and print it out:

```
for ($files_arr as $type => $file) {
    if ($type == 'css') { echo "<link href='$file'/>"; /* echo path css out */ }
    if ($type == 'js') { echo "<script src='$file'/>"; /* echo path js out */ }
}
```

Hope it would help.